# PERL WWW::Scripter not work, not return content

Tags: javascript, perl, web, scraper

Usualy I make scrapers in Ruby, but decide to do in Perl. And when I run my script I see number of url which opens very very very slow.
And I thank, maybe its redirect problem? Or maybe its JS urls thats why problem. And I decide to use some module which can open JS web sites. 
So I look to cpan doc, take code and try to run it. Nothing no content.
What I do wrong? Please correct me. Or maybe advice me smth. I try to use Selenium but have problems with installation, see error when I try to run selenium in Linux console.

```
use WWW::Scripter;

  $w = new WWW::Scripter;  
  $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');

   open(FH, "<links.csv");
   while (<FH>) {
    $url =  $_;

    if ( $url !~ /http(s)/ ) {
        $url = "http://".$url;
    }

    $w->get(url);
    $html = $w->content;

    print "=======\n";
    print Dupmper $w->content;
    print "=======\n";
}
```

Comment: Besides that, there is WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and ::Chrome. They remote-control a browser Window on your machine, so you need X when you're on Linux. ::Chrome was released like a week ago and is still not very feature-complete. It should support a headless more where you do not need a window manager. You can use it to pull out the final source code after JS stuff ran and work on that.

Comment: When I try to use Mechanize Firefox I got error - ^[[Aroot@antonov:/var/www/html/work8# perl work8.pl
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
I should run some daemon before using this module?

Comment: You need to install a Firefox add on and start it so the Perl module can talk to Firefox. There is a troubleshooting or FAQ section in the pod that explao explains how to do that. It think it is at the end. I don't have a computer right now so I can't link it. The add on is called mozrepl

Answer (score 2):

```
$w->get(url);
```

It's not `url`, it's `$url`. Use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should always `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl programs. They would have picked up your typo.

Secondly, you should have checked the return code from `get()` as that would have shown you there was something wrong.

Thirdly, there are few outdated Perl programming practices in your code.

```
# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Scripter;
# Added this
use Data::Dumper;

# Don't use indirect object notation.
# Declare variable
my $w = WWW::Scripter->new;
$w->use_plugin('JavaScript');

# Three-arg version of open()
# Lexical filehandle
# Check result of open() and die on failure
open(my $in_fh, '<', 'links.csv') or die $!;

while (<$in_fh>) {
  # Fixed regex.
  # 1/ Anchored at start of string
  # 2/ Made 's' optional (and non-captured)
  if ( ! /^https?/ ) {
    # Use string interpolation
    $url = "http://$url";
  }

  # Capture HTTP response
  # Use '$url', not 'url'
  my $resp = $w->get($url);

  # Check request is successful
  unless ($resp->is_success) {
    # If not, warn and die
    warn $resp->status_line;
    next;
  }

  print "=======\n";
  print Dumper $w->content;
  print "=======\n";
}
```

Comment: Well. It stange. It works. But when it try to parse HTML another time, I got very big error. And with LWP I dont have such error. All working pretty good, but big very big pauses when get HTML from some sites. Next is error text for you.
Use of uninitialized value $ms in division (/) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/WWW/Scripter.pm line 825.

Comment: I can publish full text of error here. But I can give you link to full error text. https://justpaste.it/18e33

Comment: If you have extra useful information to share, then please edit your question to add it.

Comment: Try to think why, why, why I can have very big pauses when try to get HTML from url. Up to hour may be more. Why?

Comment: Maybe problem with redirect?

Comment: @DenisAntonov Why do you keep suggesting completely unrelated edits to my answer? That's incredibly rude.